# View inactive posts to achieve Excavator badge

Tags: discussion

How can I view inactive posts? I am trying to earn the Excavator badge.

Answer (score 7):

You can use this SEDE query which was created exactly for this purpose: [Posts inactive for over 6 months: Useful for Archaeologist badge progress](https://data.stackexchange.com/askubuntu/query/1633507/posts-inactive-for-over-6-months-useful-for-archaeologist-badge-progress)

Or you can use advanced search options in the site's search bar. Specifically, you may use the `created:` and `lastactive:` search operators to search for posts as described in the [How do I search?](https://askubuntu.com/help/searching) section of the Help center:

> ##### Dates
>
> You can use specific dates or date ranges to narrow results down to posts created or active within a certain time period, using the following operators:
>
> - `created:` to specify when the posts were created
> - `lastactive:` for posts active in a specified time period
>
> Dates can be entered in the following formats:
>
> - Absolute dates:
>
>   - *year only* – e.g., `created:2012..2013` searches posts created from January 1, 2012 through December 31, 2013; `created:2012` searches posts created from January 1, 2012 through December 31, 2012.
>   - *year and month* – e.g., `created:2012-04..2012-05` searches posts created between April 1, 2012 and May 31, 2012.
>   - *day, month, and year* – e.g., `lastactive:2012-04-03` searches posts who were last active between 12:00 AM on April 3, 2012 and 11:59 PM on April 3, 2012.
> - Relative dates:
>
>   - `1y`, `1m`, and `1d` are shorthand for "last year", "last month", and "yesterday" – e.g., if today is April 15, `created:1m` searches posts created between March 1 and March 31. (You can substitute any number for `1` to look back that many years, months, or days.)
>   - Relative dates in a range (`1y..`) look back to the same date in the previous period – e.g., if you want to see all the posts active in the last three months, use `lastactive:3m..` On April 15, that will show posts from January 15 up to the most recently active. You can close the range as well: `lastactive:3m..1m`.
>
> **Please note** that all times are recorded in UTC; the results may not match your timezone.